# How do I replace Unity with Android UI but still have Ubuntu underneath? (without emulation)

Tags: unity, android

I would like to standardize my GUI experience but not lose the power of Ubuntu/Debian underneath. Has anyone tried to install Android on top of Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Android uses just the Linux kernel and *nothing* else. It has its own architecture, window manager, display manager, drivers and whatnot. It re-implemented everything. If you try "replacing" The GNU in GNU/Linux with Android - it'll be **nothing** like Ubuntu/Debian. In short - it's impossible to have *both*.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Android is a different operating system.

Comment: Operating System is a fuzzy term here. Both Android and Ubuntu share a commonality of the Linux kernel. Binaries on Ubuntu also work on Android. What they don't share is a similar file directory structure which might make some programs like aptitude confused.

Comment: Also note that many binaries used in Ubuntu can also run on Windows these days which is very much a different Operating System. https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/

Comment: Applications used in Ubuntu running on Windows is a very different prospect. Most of GNOME based software has been usable on Windows for over a decade, before Android even existed. The question being asked here is about running the Android UI on top of Ubuntu, as a replacement for Unity/GNOME/KDE/etc… That is not doable.